# Leave more spam to be handled by the whole community?

Tags: discussion, spam

Did we ever have a "No engage day" for posts reported by [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/)?

Due to the excellent work of Smokey and the connected rooms I'd assume a big part of the community is not even aware about spam, while IMHO the best weapon against spam would be a community knowing how to handle it, (following  **This site is moderated by you**).
Sure, there is enough spam left which Smokey did not catch, but most of this might be hard to spot for users who are not yet familiar with spam and might get removed with more observant users.

My question is:
Should we let Smokey do its work and not (or at least very late) engage; at least on the obvious spam; the tricky ones might be hinted through comments, to give the community the chance to handle it?
Due to the autoflags no post would be lost.

Downsides coming to my mind might be distraction, more traffic on meta sites, and more populated links on google.
A mod view, especially about the cons from their point of view, seems important for me.

Comment: Your main concern is that not enough users get exposed to real spam so they won't recognize it when it slips through the net? And as a result they close vote spam questions or flag as NAA instead of using a spam flag?

Comment: @rene Yes, I think most of all started with easy to spot spam and learned to judge better and  stay observant.

Comment: I think that this should [be a Charcoal GitHub issue](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/issues/new) rather than a Meta.SE question, as it's about something Charcoal-specific and is asking what we should do, and is probably more an *internal* discussion.

Comment: I know what we'll see: comments like *I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is spam.*

Comment: @Mithrandir I'm fine with a close vote, but I'm not sure if this should not be a discussion with a broader audience since it could have impact on the whole site?

Comment: @Glorfindel, maybe, but the goal would be to grow a community being able to handle it as intended.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by the sentence about autoflags. If we abstain from manual spam reporting, it would make sense to disable autoflagging, too. The autoflagging mechanism does not change whether a post is "lost" (I assume you mean recorded in Metasmoke and reported in chat).

Comment: @tripleee, not exactly, it would be flagged but not instant removed (be flags of users in the room), so other users would be able to handle it.

Comment: I still don't understand.  The autoflagging mechanism flags posts as spam on behalf of Charcoal users (or more broadly, people who signed up for this in Metasmoke at some point), so I assume this is something you would like to disable. The record of what posts Smoke Detector has produced an alert for does not depend on autoflagging (though obviously there is a dependency the other way -- no alert means definitely no autoflags).  I imagine you would like to change that sentence to something like "We would still record all suspicious posts in Metasmoke and produce alerts for them in chat rooms."

Comment: In other words, autoflagging automates the flagging we otherwise do manually, which I understand you want us to stop doing briefly. Ref: https://charcoal-se.org/flagging

Comment: FWIW, if Smokey doesn't alert Charcoalers of spam in quieter sites, a spam post would be able to sit for hours in at least half of the SE. You also risk completely uninitiated people doing something just for the sake of doing it, like upvoting spam just to get a review done.

Comment: @M.A.R. quieter sites are an argument, the other point I would have seen as learning by doing, maybe I'm to optimistic.

Comment: There are sites like SU where that dragon guy leads a spam-attack teaching campaign, and has cool lists on meta of known spammers and such, but if a site doesn't have an active and eager teacher like that, who leads the in-community spam-fighting, my experience says people would neither want to teach nor learn.

Comment: A pity, if it really should be like that.

Answer (score 9):

There are a few reasons why I think it is good to insta-delete the spam instead of letting it stay for the community to handle.

#### 1. There are spam reviews

We are trying to educate users to identify and handle spam correctly by letting them judge review audits. The positive side here is that there is feedback when the user does take the wrong action. When a user votes to close a question for spam reasons, they often don't stay around to get to read the comment from another user how to handle it.

#### 2. Deterence

We want spam to be gone as soon as possible, to deter spammers to place it in the first place. Why let them have their 30 minutes of fame when it can be deleted instantly? They will notice it gets deleted in 6 seconds, and hopefully they will adjust their plan based on that.

#### 3. Identifying spam can be hard when you don't know the details

Smoke Detector knows some patterns in spam. Users don't. Why not let Smoke Detector catch those instead of letting the community find out it actually is spam. (Remember those Android recovery tools spam?)

#### 4. No spam, no need to handle it

Do we really need users to understand spam flagging if Smoke Detector can create a 99.9% catch rate? I don't think so.

Comment: `Do we really need users to understand spam flagging if Smoke Detector can create a 99.9% catch rate? I don't think so.` - *yes*. Smokey isn't infallible - it can go down, and we were having some problems a couple weeks ago. I don't want users to be utterly dependent on one group of volunteers and a chatbot, who aren't even officially affiliated with SE. If Smokey goes down for a day, what happens then?

Comment: That is definitely true. I think that will grow the same as when there is a new review queue introduced. The community adapts. One meta post will help users to understand what to do.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Stack Exchange has handled spam long before Smoke Detector was in operation. Not to diminish the aid of the bot, but the anti-spam system that SE put into place a while ago had a much larger impact on overall spam volume than Smoke Detector has. That hasn't changed the way that the community is able to respond to spam. Just because spam is getting deleted before most people see it doesn't mean that the average SE member won't recognize BUY R@L3X HERE garbage. The review system is pretty good at picking that out.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think your argument's basis is correct. You're saying that, because the Charcoal project exists, less users are aware of what spam is, and how to appropriately deal with it. Let me present a few counterarguments:

1. Details of how to deal with spam are discussed in each site's help center. Specifically, the [flagging page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/flagging) discusses how to appropriately flag inappropriate posts. If a user reads the help center (as they should!), then they will have plenty of information about how flagging works, and how to deal with spam (as well as other types of inappropriate posts). If they have further questions, Meta.SE has plenty of information. On the other hand, if a user doesn't read the help center, then the presence of the Charcoal project doesn't make much of a difference - the user still wouldn't know how to appropriately handle spam even if it didn't exist.
2. The Charcoal project is an enhancement for regular spam handling, not a replacement. Its purpose is to make it easier to detect spam, so that it can be destroyed faster. Even with autoflagging active, destroying spam still requires human intervention - only a maximum of 3 autoflags are cast on a given post, and that's only if the system is *really really really really* sure that it's spam (based on patterns that human users have noticed and added to the system's filters). It does not replace users dealing with spam - it just helps kill spam faster, which is a goal we all share.
3. Charcoal HQ is a very good resource for learning about spam and how to effectively fight it. I've seen more conversations about what technically constitutes spam and where the line between spam and not-spam lies in Charcoal HQ than anywhere else on the network (though I am biased - I spend a lot of time lurking in Charcoal HQ, and not nearly as much time reading [spam](/questions/tagged/spam) posts on Meta.SE). In this way, the Charcoal project serves not only to quash spam faster, but also as a resource to learn how to recognize spam and flag it appropriately.

If autoflagging were to be shut down for a day, the only tangible result would be that spam lingers around slightly longer on that day. That is obviously not desirable. The faster spam dies, the better off everyone is. In my opinion, if users don't see spam, and therefore aren't as experienced at recognizing it, that's a *good thing*. If the spam dies too fast for most users to see it... Mission accomplished.

Comment: I sort of take it that having the spam visible for longer is sort of the point here, though I too disagree that it would actually be beneficial or desirable.

Comment: @tripleee Having the spam visible for longer means that there is more time for people to click on the links and have whatever negative consequences from whichever flavor of spam it is. We agree that nobody wants that to happen (except the spammers, but they don't count).

Comment: @Mego, I see the downsides on longer staying links, but I'd assume most of the users are not even aware of meta sites and do not look into help.

Comment: @bummi If users are not going to take advantage of the readily-available resources about moderation and spam removal, I highly doubt that seeing more spam will make much of a difference.